# Shiur for when shaatnez prohibits an item

Tags: halacha, clothing, shiurim-measurements, shaatnez

According to Halacha, what is the minimum shiur (size) of shaatnez in a garment for it to become prohibited to wear?

Is it even a single thread, a certain amount of inches, etc.?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The Rambam (MT [Kilayim 10:5](https://www.sefaria.org/Mishneh_Torah%2C_Diverse_Species.10.5?lang=bi)) answers your question

> **There is no minimum measure for *kilayim***. **Even the smallest thread** of
> wool in a large linen garment or a thread of linen in a woolen garment
> **is forbidden**.

R Elyahu Touger explains why (based on Tosafot Nidah 61b)

> Generally,
> a forbidden entity can become nullified, because it is of no
> consequence when compared to the kosher substance into which it is
> mixed. Such logic does not apply in this instance, because **there is no
> prohibited object to be nullified. Both the linen and the wool are
> permitted. Hence, they remain significant no matter how small an
> amount there is.**

Comment: The halacha is clear, but according to Rav Chaim Kanievsky z"l (Derech Emunah ad loc.),  the Rambam understands the reason differently.